# Model evaluation in R with confusion matrix

Tags: r, machine-learning

Hi I have used the ROCR package to check the performance of a model, I would like to do more evaluation like a confusion matrix with kappa values or k fold.
below are the model and the predictions, any help would be great.

```
   model <- cv.glmnet(sparesemx[train.set,],
            first.round[train.set],
            alpha = 0.05,
            family = 'binomial')

 training$sparse.fr.hat <- predict(model, newx = sparesemx, type = 
 'response')[,1]

predictions <- prediction(training$sparse.fr.hat[test.set], 
first.round[test.set])
perform <- performance(predictions, 'tpr', 'fpr')
plot(perform)
performance(predictions, 'auc')
```

I am trying to use the caret library with the confusionMatrix() function but I am unable to generate the matrix. I have tried several inputs for the two agruments but I am not sure what is needed

Comment: Please be more specific - it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: apologies, I am trying to do generate a confusion matrix with the above model and predictions but I am having issues.

Comment: Then include what you have tried so far, along with the said issues!

Comment: I am using the library Caret, I have been using confusionMatrix(predictions, ???) but after reading the help section I am unsure what the two arguments for the matrix should be...

Comment: `confusionMatrix(predicted_values, true_values)` - in any case, locate some of the (numerous) tutorials available with known datasets and *experiment* to gain familiarity, before delving directly into unknown ground...

Comment: Add to `caret` the package `OptimalCutpoints`.  You have to choose a criteria for your cutoff.  Work through some examples in `OptimalCutpoints` and then apply what you learn there to the stuff in `caret`.

Comment: It would be great if you can clarify a bit more by editing the question. Do you mean you would like to also get the performance evaluation based on the different confusion matrix based measures? In that case you can used caret and configure one or more custom measures, or, you can write your own loop to do k-fold (using `caret::createFolds`crossvalidation or bootstrap sampling. After processing each fold, compute the confusion matrix or confusion matrix based measures.

Answer (score 1):

Worked example, step by step in explicit detail.

```
library(OptimalCutpoints)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(e1071)

data(elas) #predicting for variable "status"
```

Split the `elas` data into training (dev) and testing (val)

```
sample.ind <- sample(2, 
                     nrow(elas),
                     replace = T,
                     prob = c(0.6,0.4))
elas.dev <- elas[sample.ind==1,]
elas.val <- elas[sample.ind==2,]
```

This example uses a logistic model so this is how the formula is specified, similar to your `sparesemx` matrix.

```
formula.glm<-glm(status ~ gender + elas, data = elas, family = binomial)
xfactors<-model.matrix(formula.glm)[,-1]

glmnet.x<-as.matrix(xfactors)
glmmod<-glmnet(x=glmnet.x[sample.ind==1,],y=elas.dev$status,alpha=1,
               family='binomial')


#if you care; the lasso model includes both predictors
#cv.glmmod <- cv.glmnet(x=glmnet.x[sample.ind==1,], y=elas.dev$status, alpha=1, family='binomial')
#plot(cv.glmmod)
#cv.glmmod$lambda.min
#coef(cv.glmmod, s="lambda.min")
```

Now you have to get the predicted for the status variable using the two selected predictors from glmnet, which you did.

```
bestglm<-glm(status ~ gender + elas, data = elas.dev, family = binomial)
```

**You got as far as around here.**  I'm using the `fitted.values` from my object and you're using `prediction` but you should get a column of actual values and fitted values.  This doesn't tell you where the cutpoint is.  Where do you draw the line between what is "positive" and what is "negative"?

I suggest using `OptimalCutpoints` for this.

Set this up for `optimal.cutpoints`; the container thing that comes next is just a `data.frame` where both variables have the same length.  It contains actual versus predicted from the glm.

```
container.for.OC<-data.frame(fit=bestglm$fitted.values, truth=elas.dev$status)
```

I am using the Youden criteria here but there are many choices for the criteria.

```
optimal.cutpoint.Youden<-optimal.cutpoints(X = fit  ~ truth , tag.healthy = 0, 
        methods = "Youden", pop.prev = NULL,  data=container.for.OC,
        control = control.cutpoints(), ci.fit = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, trace = FALSE)


summary(optimal.cutpoint.Youden)
```

Here is what I got:

```
Area under the ROC curve (AUC):  0.818 (0.731, 0.905) 

CRITERION: Youden
Number of optimal cutoffs: 1

                    Estimate
cutoff             0.4863188
Se                 0.9180328
Sp                 0.5882353
PPV                0.8000000
NPV                0.8000000
DLR.Positive       2.2295082
DLR.Negative       0.1393443
FP                14.0000000
FN                 5.0000000
Optimal criterion  0.5062681

#not run
#plot(optimal.cutpoint.Youden)
```

Now apply what you've learned from the Youden cutoff to your validation set, `elas.val`.

This should match the cutoff from the table above.

```
MaxYoudenCutoff <- optimal.cutpoint.Youden$Youden$Global$optimal.cutoff$cutoff
```

This will give you the predicted levels from the Youden cutpoint.  They have to be a factor object for your `confusionMatrix` function.

```
val.predicted<-predict(object=bestglm, newdata=elas.val, type="response")
val.factor.level<-factor(ifelse(val.predicted >=MaxYoudenCutoff,"1","0"))
```

Like before, make a small container for the `confusionMatrix` function.

```
container.for.CM <- data.frame(truth=factor(elas.val$status), fit=val.factor.level)
confusionMatrix(data=container.for.CM$fit, reference=container.for.CM$truth)

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  0  1
         0  7  8
         1  6 37

               Accuracy : 0.7586          
                 95% CI : (0.6283, 0.8613)
    No Information Rate : 0.7759          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.6895          

                  Kappa : 0.342           
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.7893          

            Sensitivity : 0.5385          
            Specificity : 0.8222          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.4667          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.8605          
             Prevalence : 0.2241          
         Detection Rate : 0.1207          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.2586          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.6803          

       'Positive' Class : 0
```